# What differences are there between running monotouch in simulator vs. on device?

Tags: ios-simulator, xamarin.ios, jit, aot

Is there any documentation on the difference between the monotouch runtime used in (iPad) Simulator vs. running on an actual device?

I've recently had to change some code that resulted in ExecutionEngineException (seemingly unrelated to the one mentioned [here](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Troubleshoot#System.ExecutionEngineException.3a_Attempting_to_JIT_compile_method_%28wrapper_managed-to-managed%29_Foo.5b.5d.3aSystem.Collections.Generic.ICollection.601.get_Count_%28%29)) when running on the device, but not in the simulator.

Is JIT enabled in the simulator (I know it is not on the device) or why is there this difference?

(Question also posted to Monotouch forums [here](http://forums.monotouch.net/yaf_postsm3954.aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS simulator is a simulator and not an emulator.  This means that when running on the simulator you have access to a full x86 JIT, where as on the device you can only do ARM full-aot.  There are a number of other subtle differences as well (certain frameworks / features are not available on the simulator).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Geoff. Will wait and see if anyone can point me to any official documentation on this, otherwise I'll accept your answer.

Comment: But I thought the simulator is the one that comes with Xcode and will therefore run "Apple binaries"? So how would it know about JIT or AOT at all?

Comment: Markus, Apple's documentation is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html  It doesn't specifically call out the x86 versus ARM changes, but they are certainly there as well.

Comment: Krumelur, the binaries for the simulator and device are completely different.

Comment: Markus, Geoff Norton is one of the guys behind MonoTouch developmet so i guess his answer its more than official :)

Comment: dalexsoto: thanks, still surprised it not documented. Geoff: is it possible/are there plans to turn on aot in the simulator to have the same behavior as on the device?

Comment: There are no plans to do this at this time, as it would significantly slow down build times on the simulator, effectively removing the fast compile/test/edit/repeat cycle.

Comment: I would value being able to trust the /test/ part though. Perhaps as an option? Anyway, thank you for all your work and thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

One thing to remember about Simulator/iDevice is the configuration used. Double check the linking behavior. You can get subtle errors if you use Reflection and the linker removed a Get or Set method of a property you thought was there.

This hit me a few times.